# Encerrar sessão e redirecionar usuário para tela de login ASP NET MVC / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timeout

Estou procurando uma forma de encerrar minha sessão e redirecionar o usuário para a tela de login quando meu sistema der **TimeOut**.

Tentei usar Session.Abandon() conforme alguns exemplos que pesquisei. Porém não sei o que estou fazendo de errado. segue abaixo meu código:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var redirectLocation = context.Response.RedirectLocation.ToString();

            context.Response.RedirectLocation = null;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("session_timeout;" + redirectLocation);

            context.Session.Abandon();
            context.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
        }
    }
```

O código é executado apenas até : ***context.Session.Abandon();*** e não redireciona para a tela de login, salvo se eu der **refresh** na página.

Comment: Não sei em Asp.net MVC, mas em WebForms existe um arquivo chamado `Global.asax` que toda vez que a sessão inspira o método   `void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)` é chamado.

Comment: @Marconi o Gloabal.asax também existe em asp net mvc, esse código está dentro dele, mas ainda não funciona. Obrigado

Comment: Coloca um break point dentro do método.

Comment: Eu coloquei o break point, porém ele não chega nesse ponto  **context.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");**

Comment: Coloca no if pra ver se as condições estão satisfazendo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll();            
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Não lembro de cabeça agora se este trecho de código já faz o redirecionamento para a tela de login, mas caso não faça você pode usar seu redirecionamento:

```
context.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
```

**EDIT**

Tente então trocar o tipo do seu Método de `void` para `ActionResult` e retornar um `RedirectToAction()`:

```
//Mesmo Código Acima...
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

Usando sua View e Controller de Login

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta, mas não faz o redirecionamento para a página, mesmo usando. **context.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");**

Comment: Alterei a resposta para outra Alternativa, tente mais uma vez! :D

Comment: Só precisa de return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

Comment: Verdade @GustavoCorreiaSantos to na correria e nem me liguei! Obrigado, já editei

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, isso funcionária. Porém fico com uma dúvida. Se eu implementar essa solução usando meu Controller de Login, eu poderia verificar se um usuário teve timeout? o que quero dizer é... para um usuário já logado, posso fazer verificação se deu timeout e redirecionar para a tela de login? eu acredito que não, pois eu precisaria chamar meu ActionResult todas as vezes de qualquer parte do meu sistema. Obs: não sei se estou errado

Comment: Eu retirei o `context.Session.Abandon();` é o redirecionamento funcionou... porém, ele chama a view de Login em cima da view atual, quebrando assim minha tela...